# Align text on same row

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with showing binded data in same row.

I want to show it like this:

2018-01-01 - 2018-01-07

```
<Label Text="{Binding ChartDate, StringFormat='{0:d}'}"></Label>   
<Label Text="-"></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding ChartDateTo, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" ></Label>
```

How's that done? I tried to move the second binding to first label but then nothing shows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackLayout.Children>
        <Label Text="{Binding ChartDate, StringFormat='{0:d}'}"></Label> 
        <Label Text="-"></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding ChartDateTo, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" ></Label> 
    </StackLayout.Children>
</StackLayout>
```